# CSS inset border color incorrect

Tags: css

I am trying use border inset with a light color for the inset, but, the colors chosen are simply not being shown correctly, this is the same in every browser

Here's the css - first box should have light inset border and second box slightly darker:

Here a fiddle: [CSS inset border Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/J89wg/)

```
.box1 {
display: inline-block;
border: 4px inset #f7f7f7;
margin-top: 16px; 
border-radius: 12px;
height: 34px;
background:#fff;
width:230px;
position:relative;
padding:10px;
}

.box2 {
display: inline-block;
border: 4px inset #cccccc;
margin-top: 16px;
border-radius: 12px;
height: 34px;
background:#f7f7f7;
width:230px;
position:relative;
padding:10px;
}
```

I've tried setting the border-color element separately but it makes no difference

Very odd behaviour?

Comment: That is the way a 3D inset border is simulated on a flat screen. More and less light (brighter and darker colors) to fake the effect. The behavior is not odd and as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the inset border works in the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-style-properties). The bottom and right sides are lighter than the top and left; the latter two are the set color. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style for all border options.

Comment: If you're going to say "spec", please actually cite the spec... http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-style

Comment: I added a link to the CSS2 spec (for the sake of IE)

Comment: Eh, that particular section of B&B level 3 is the same for IE, but that doesn't matter. Thanks for the edit.